# Admin page webmatrix i already have a *.cshtml file in root folder?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I am unable to see _admin page in Web Matrix. i already contain a *.cshtml file in root. Also my nuget package manager keeps on uninstalling itself please help me i am new with all this.

Answer (score 0):

If you name a file with an underscore like `_admin.cshtml`, you will not be able to access it directly. You will however be able to navigate to it if you name it `admin.cshtml`.

Usually you will want to use underscores on the name when working with things like `RenderPage` or Layout pages: `_Layout.cshtml`.

This article has some helpful information on using Layout pages: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983489.aspx